# Finding out various sine values from its graph.

Tags: trigonometry

Question (and Answer): [image: Question and Answer]

The answer is written in thin black, inc = increasing, dec = decreasing. Am I wrong anywhere?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are absolutely right in the increasing and decreasing value. Just when the graph goes up its increasing and when it comes down its decreasing.

Its actually like lets have a function$f(x)$ and let $x_1$and $x_2$ be in its domain(the values the function can take up)

> If a function is increasing then
>   lets say that $$ x_1<x_2$$ 
>   then $$f(x_1)<f(x_2)$$ and if the function is decreasing, if $$ x_1<x_2$$ then $$ f(x_1)>f(x_2)$$

Hope it helps.